# NextJS não executa no Visual Studio Code, mas funciona no pront de comando

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, next.js

Olá, criei uma aplicação padrão do NextJS usando **`"npx create-next-app teste"`**, não alterei nenhum arquivo padrão e no prompt de comando (CMD) do Windows, quando eu uso comandos como **`"npm start", "npm run dev"`** e etc. A aplicação roda perfeitamente.

Quando eu uso os mesmos comandos usando o terminal do Visual Studio Code a aplicação da erro.

**Observação:** Eu sempre uso o terminal do Visual Studio, atualmente roda tudo, aplicação em Node, em React e etc. Consigo usar qualquer comando, até ações especificas para mexer no sistema do Windows, Apenas NextJS da erro.

**Estrutura do aplicativo original:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVoKM.png

**Executando no terminal:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjGK9.png

**Executando no Visual Studio:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EH7q.png

**Executando no Visual Studio erro 2:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez73N.png

**Erro no terminal do Visual Studio:**

```
PS E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs> npm run dev

> nextjs@0.1.0 dev E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
warn  - ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireDefault.js
    Used by 5 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireDefault.js
    Used by 11 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\client\next-dev.js

./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard.js  
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireWildcard.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js

Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react-is\cjs\react-is.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react-is\index.js
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react-is\cjs\react-is.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react-is\index.js

./node_modules/react-is/index.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react-is\index.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react-is\index.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js

./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react\index.js
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react\index.js

./node_modules/react/index.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react\index.js
    Used by 9 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js
* E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\react\index.js
    Used by 28 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\Frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!E:\Apps\Dhenyson-site\frontend\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js
info  - ready on http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Seria bom ver essa mensagem.

Comment: Provavelmente a pasta .next não foi criada ou foi criada com algo dentro Essa discussão no github provavelmente vai te ajudar https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14394

Comment: Augusto, eu coloquei o resto da mensagem. Diego, a pasta .next foi criada, li o link que você passou, mas infezlimente se trata de outro problema. Não entendo porque pelo terminal do Windows roda normalmente, e eu já uso Next a um tempo e nunca tive esse tipo de erro e não acho na internet. Mas deixei todas informações aqui para tentar solucionar.

Comment: Não entendo porque dão dislike... é um problema que já procurei na net e não achei, perguntei diretamente a programador de mais de 15 anos de profissão e não resolveu... ou seja, 100% valido para eu colocar aqui no stackoverflow que pode ajudar outras pessoas... enfim, estou estudando o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolver, um erro muito simples e básico. Quando eu abria o app com Visual Studio Code, por algum motivo ele mudava o "F" do caminho /Frontend para "f" minúsculo. Bem, em todos projetos aqui percebi que o VS Code esta fazendo isso e mesmo assim outros apps de outras tecnologias não dão erro, por isso foi mesmo simples foi tão difícil pensar neste problema.

**E para resolver eu apenas fiz:** No terminal do **VS Code** sair da pasta (`cd..`) e entrei novamente colocando o caminho correto (`cd Frontend`). Apenas isso resolveu um problema que estava dando dor de cabeça enorme... agora só preciso saber porque o VS Code esta mudando os **path** para minúsculo.